# Navigation Property to 'Child object' in 'Parent child collection' on 'Parent'

Tags: entity-framework

Is there any way to save a child object in a parents child object collection and also setting it to a navigation property on the parent without round tripping to the database? example below doesn't work

```
public class Parent
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    int? ChildId { get; set; }
    Child Child { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
public class Child
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}

....

var p = new Parent();
var c = new Child();

p.Child = c;
p.Children.Add(c);

Context.Set<Parent>().Add(p);
Context.SaveChanges();
```

***EDIT***

The example above throws this error when 'savechanges()' is called.

> Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.

Comment: Doesn't work is a bit vague - what error do you get and at what point in the code?

Comment: @qujck fair enough... added the exception thrown when the code example is run.

Comment: You should be using `Context.Set<>().Create()` instead of new'ing up the Entities but the error indicates there may some issue with the mapping of the entities ...